# Activate element on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm attempting to have an autoscroll effect on my page so after a video plays, the website will slowly scroll down allowing the user to read the contents without actively scrolling.

That said, once I reach the bottom, I want it to automatically stop. Currently, it will continue scrolling down indefinitely making it impossible to scroll back up after you reach the bottom.

This is the code I have for the scroll and delay (to allow the video to play):

```
<script>
function pageScroll() {
    window.scrollBy(0, 1); 
    scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 10); 
}
</script>

<body onLoad="setTimeout('pageScroll()', 14000)">

    Thanks for your help!

</body>
```

Comment: Are the tags correct? It feels like plain HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `pageScroll` function should look like:

```
function pageScroll() {
  // Start interval - run the function every 1000 ms
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    window.scrollBy(0,1); 
    // Did the scroll reach the bottom of the page?
    if (document.body.scrollHeight === document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) {
      // Cancel the interval
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dngwv4pr/2/

More reading:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval

Comment: Thanks! Works great! What would I replace to get it to stop at a particular spot thats not at the bottom?

Comment: nevermind! got it if (document.body.scrollTop > 5000)